# Excel to DataTable using EPPlus - excel locked for editing

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using the following code to convert an Excel to a datatable using EPPlus:

```
public DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string path)
{
    var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
    pck.Load(File.OpenRead(path));
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    bool hasHeader = true;
    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
    {
        tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
    }
    var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
    for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
    {
        var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
        var row = tbl.NewRow();
        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
        {
            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
        }
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    pck.Dispose();
    return tbl;
}
```

It creates the Excel, however, when I try to open it, it gives me the message that it is locked for editing by another user and that I can only open it in Read-Only mode.

I thought using:

```
pck.Dispose();
```

would solve the issue, however I'm still getting the same error.

Also, when I try to delete the file, I get the message: The action can't be completed because the file is open in WebDev.WebServer40.EXE.

Any ideas how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I see, that's what [I've posted recently here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11239895/284240) (now corrected). It can be improved since the `ExcelPackage` and the `FileStream` (from `File.OpenRead`) are not disposed after using.

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, bool hasHeader = true)
{
    using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            pck.Load(stream);
        }
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();  
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
        }
        var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
        for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
        {
            var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
            DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
            foreach (var cell in wsRow)
            {
                row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            }
        }
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I saw the code on the Codeplex EPPlus site as well as on your post on StackOverflow.
Tried this, works, thanks a ton :)
pck.Dispose() just disposes the ExcelPackage then and not the FileStream, correct?

Comment: @Fahad: Correct. It's also better to use `using` since it also disposes the `IDisposable` on errors. I'll edit the post on Codeplex as well.

Comment: How can i get first column in "foreach (var cell in wsRow){" this loop
Becoz i have a date field and i want to change format while inserting into datatable so i need to check data into "foreach (var cell in wsRow){" loop so how can i identified that first colunm value is come?

Comment: @TimSchmelter my excel have first 2 row as junk info and third row contain all the columns and rest of rows are data. How i can skip first 2 rows? am using exact same code.thanks in advance for help.

Comment: please let me know if there a way to remove empty cells from the ws.Dimension.End.Column? or select only the range which has data?

Comment: I get the type or name `OfficeOpenXml` cannot be found. I've already added a reference to EPPlus

Comment: Replace cell.Text with cell.Value if you have precision numbers otherwise the Text string if converted back to e.g. decimal may be an approximated value instead of the more precise Value

Comment: I am getting error in File.OpenRead(path)

Answer (score 12):

A extension version of Tim Schmelter's answer.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this ExcelWorksheet ws, bool hasHeaderRow = true)
{
    var tbl = new DataTable();
    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
        tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeaderRow ?
            firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
    var startRow = hasHeaderRow ? 2 : 1;
    for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
    {
        var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
        var row = tbl.NewRow();
        foreach (var cell in wsRow) row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return tbl;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've created a method that converts an Excel file to a DataTable using EPPlus, and tried to maintain Type Safety. Also duplicate column names are handled and with a boolean you can tell the method wether the sheet has a row with headers. I've created it for a complex import process that has several steps after uploading that requires user input before committing to the database.

```
private DataTable ExcelToDataTable(byte[] excelDocumentAsBytes, bool hasHeaderRow)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string errorMessages = "";

    //create a new Excel package in a memorystream
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(excelDocumentAsBytes))
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

        //check if the worksheet is completely empty
        if (worksheet.Dimension == null)
        {
            return dt;
        }

        //add the columns to the datatable
        for (int j = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
        {
            string columnName = "Column " + j;
            var excelCell = worksheet.Cells[1, j].Value;

            if (excelCell != null)
            {
                var excelCellDataType = excelCell;

                //if there is a headerrow, set the next cell for the datatype and set the column name
                if (hasHeaderRow == true)
                {
                    excelCellDataType = worksheet.Cells[2, j].Value;

                    columnName = excelCell.ToString();

                    //check if the column name already exists in the datatable, if so make a unique name
                    if (dt.Columns.Contains(columnName) == true)
                    {
                        columnName = columnName + "_" + j;
                    }
                }

                //try to determine the datatype for the column (by looking at the next column if there is a header row)
                if (excelCellDataType is DateTime)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(DateTime));
                }
                else if (excelCellDataType is Boolean)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(Boolean));
                }
                else if (excelCellDataType is Double)
                {
                    //determine if the value is a decimal or int by looking for a decimal separator
                    //not the cleanest of solutions but it works since excel always gives a double
                    if (excelCellDataType.ToString().Contains(".") || excelCellDataType.ToString().Contains(","))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(Decimal));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(Int64));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(String));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(String));
            }
        }

        //start adding data the datatable here by looping all rows and columns
        for (int i = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row + Convert.ToInt32(hasHeaderRow); i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
        {
            //create a new datatable row
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            //loop all columns
            for (int j = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
            {
                var excelCell = worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value;

                //add cell value to the datatable
                if (excelCell != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        row[j - 1] = excelCell;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        errorMessages += "Row " + (i - 1) + ", Column " + j + ". Invalid " + dt.Columns[j - 1].DataType.ToString().Replace("System.", "") + " value:  " + excelCell.ToString() + "<br>";
                    }
                }
            }

            //add the new row to the datatable
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    //show error messages if needed
    Label1.Text = errorMessages;

    return dt;
}
```

The webforms button click for demo purposes.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        DataTable dt = ExcelToDataTable(FileUpload1.FileBytes, CheckBox1.Checked);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is method works for me. Unfortunately Tim's answer while shorter did not, and failed to calculate the total rows throwing an error.

Comment: Determining the type this way is error prone if you can't be absolutely sure of the contents of the sheet. The second row may be empty, or may contain an integer value while another row holds a double, and you will run into trouble and lose data

Comment: Thanks for this method VDWWD, I addressed some issues in an updated answer below.

Answer (score 6):

VDWWD's answer above works great to keep type safety, and I built upon it with some improvements.

- Method reads from a file directly.
- Column type detection by using all rows and not just one value. Column type is set to String if more than type is found in the column.
- Error Messages returned in a list of strings.

Here is the updated version:

```
    public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string path, ref List<string> errorList, bool hasHeaderRow = true  )
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        errorList = new List<string>();

        //create a new Excel package           
        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                excelPackage.Load(stream);
            }

            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

            //check if the worksheet is completely empty
            if (worksheet.Dimension == null)
            {
                return dt;
            }

            //add the columns to the datatable
            for (int j = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
            {
                string columnName = "Column " + j;


                //Build hashset with all types in the row
                var columnTypes = new HashSet<Type>();                   
                for (int i = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row + Convert.ToInt32(hasHeaderRow); i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
                {
                    //Only add type if cell value not empty
                    if (worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null)
                    {
                        columnTypes.Add(worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.GetType());
                    }
                }

                var excelCell = worksheet.Cells[1, j].Value;


                if (excelCell != null)
                {
                    Type excelCellDataType = null;

                    //if there is a headerrow, set the next cell for the datatype and set the column name
                    if (hasHeaderRow == true)
                    {

                        columnName = excelCell.ToString();

                        //check if the column name already exists in the datatable, if so make a unique name
                        if (dt.Columns.Contains(columnName) == true)
                        {
                            columnName = columnName + "_" + j;
                        }
                    }

                    //Select  input type for the column
                    if (columnTypes.Count == 1)
                    {
                        excelCellDataType = columnTypes.First();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        excelCellDataType = typeof(string);
                    }

                    //try to determine the datatype for the column (by looking at the next column if there is a header row)
                    if (excelCellDataType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(DateTime));
                    }
                    else if (excelCellDataType == typeof(Boolean))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(Boolean));
                    }
                    else if (excelCellDataType == typeof(Double))
                    {
                        //determine if the value is a decimal or int by looking for a decimal separator
                        //not the cleanest of solutions but it works since excel always gives a double
                        if (excelCellDataType.ToString().Contains(".") || excelCellDataType.ToString().Contains(","))
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(Decimal));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(Int64));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(String));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(String));
                }
            }

            //start adding data the datatable here by looping all rows and columns
            for (int i = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row + Convert.ToInt32(hasHeaderRow); i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
            {
                //create a new datatable row
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

                //loop all columns
                for (int j = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
                {
                    var excelCell = worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value;

                    //add cell value to the datatable
                    if (excelCell != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            row[j - 1] = excelCell;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            errorList.Add("Row " + (i - 1) + ", Column " + j + ". Invalid " + dt.Columns[j - 1].DataType.ToString().Replace("System.", "") + " value:  " + excelCell.ToString() );
                        }
                    }
                }

                //add the new row to the datatable
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an improvement to the generic one above. Use is if you have a class with the following properties,  "Name", "Surname", "Telephone", "Fax" and you have a excel sheet with the first row with the same names, it will load the excel rows into a class object and pop it into a List

```
public static List<T> GetClassFromExcel<T>(string path, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow = 0, int toColumn = 0)
{
if (toColumn != 0 && toColumn < fromColumn) throw new          Exception("toColumn can not be less than fromColumn");
if (toRow != 0 && toRow < fromRow) throw new Exception("toRow can not be less than fromRow");
List<T> retList = new List<T>();
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            //Retrieve first Worksheet
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            //If the to column is empty or 0, then make the tocolumn to the count of the properties
            //Of the class object inserted
            toColumn = toColumn == 0 ? typeof(T).GetProperties().Count() : toColumn;

            //Read the first Row for the column names and place into a list so that
            //it can be used as reference to properties
            Dictionary<string, int> columnNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            // wsRow = ws.Row(0);
            var colPosition = 0;
            foreach (var cell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, toColumn == 0 ? ws.Dimension.Columns : toColumn])
            {
                columnNames.Add(cell.Value.ToString(), colPosition);
                colPosition++;
            }
            //create a instance of T
            T objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            //Retrieve the type of T
            Type myType = typeof(T);
            //Get all the properties associated with T
            PropertyInfo[] myProp = myType.GetProperties();


            //Loop through the rows of the excel sheet
            for (var rowNum = fromRow; rowNum <= (toRow == 0? ws.Dimension.End.Row : toRow); rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, fromColumn, rowNum, ws.Cells.Count()];

                foreach (var propertyInfo in myProp)
                {
                    if (columnNames.ContainsKey(propertyInfo.Name))
                    {
                        int position = 0;
                        columnNames.TryGetValue(propertyInfo.Name, out position);
                        //int position = columnNames.IndexOf(propertyInfo.Name);
                        //To prevent an exception cast the value to the type of the property.
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(objT, Convert.ChangeType(wsRow[rowNum, position + 1].Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
                    }
                }

                retList.Add(objT);
            }

        }
        return retList;
    }
```

now you can use the list as a databinding source if you need...
A give from me to you... :) Daniel C. Vrey

Updated it for toColumn to work and added toRow and followed Andreas suggestions. Thumbs up for Andreas

Comment: When calling this code- what should I pass T as it requires 1 arguments :             XLReader.GetClassFromExcel<>();

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! Some remarks: (1) toColumn is not actually used and can be ignored, (2) ws.Cells.Count() crashes on me, better is to use ws.Dimension.Columns, (3) Contains and IndexOf isn't very efficient, better use a Dictionary<string, int> and query with TryGetValue. Or if you want to stick with the List, IndexOf returns -1 if item is not found, so you don't need the extra Contains() check. (4) you can move the code that calls myType.GetProperties() before the for loop so that you do it only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<T> getClassFromExcel<T>(string path, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toColumn = 0) where T : class
        {
            using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
            {
                List<T> retList = new List<T>();

                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
                {
                    pck.Load(stream);
                }
                var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                toColumn = toColumn == 0 ? typeof(T).GetProperties().Count() : toColumn;

                for (var rowNum = fromRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                {
                    T objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    Type myType = typeof(T);
                    PropertyInfo[] myProp = myType.GetProperties();

                    var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, fromColumn, rowNum, toColumn];

                    for (int i = 0; i < myProp.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        myProp[i].SetValue(objT, wsRow[rowNum, fromColumn + i].Text);
                    }
                    retList.Add(objT);
                }
                return retList;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add at least the slightest bit of explanation for your answer?

Comment: This example is to import data into List Collection not into DataTable

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<T> GetClassFromExcel<T>(string path, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int toRow = 0, int toColumn = 0) where T: class, new()
{
        if (toColumn != 0 && toColumn < fromColumn) throw new Exception("toColumn can not be less than fromColumn");
        if (toRow != 0 && toRow < fromRow) throw new Exception("toRow can not be less than fromRow");
        List<T> retList = new List<T>();
        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            //Retrieve first Worksheet
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

            toColumn = toColumn == 0 ? typeof(T).GetProperties().Count() : toColumn; //If the to column is empty or 0, then make the tocolumn to the count of the properties Of the class object inserted

            //Read the first Row for the column names and place into a list so that
            //it can be used as reference to properties
            Dictionary<string, int> columnNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            // wsRow = ws.Row(0);
            var colPosition = 0;
            foreach (var cell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, toColumn == 0 ? ws.Dimension.Columns : toColumn])
            {
                columnNames.Add(cell.Value.ToString(), colPosition);
                colPosition++;
            }

            //Retrieve the type of T
            Type myType = typeof(T);

            //Get all the properties associated with T
            PropertyInfo[] myProp = myType.GetProperties();

            //Loop through the rows of the excel sheet
            for (var rowNum = fromRow + 1; rowNum <= (toRow == 0 ? ws.Dimension.End.Row : toRow); rowNum++) // fromRow + 1 to read from next row after columnheader
            {

                //create a instance of T
                //T objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                T objT = new T();

                // var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, fromColumn, rowNum, ws.Cells.Count()]; //ws.Cells.Count() causing out of range error hence using ws.Dimension.Columns to get last column index 
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, fromColumn, rowNum, ws.Dimension.Columns];
                foreach (var propertyInfo in myProp)
                {
                    var attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
                    string displayName = attribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.DisplayName) ? attribute.DisplayName : propertyInfo.Name; // If DisplayName annotation not used then get property name itself                       
                    if (columnNames.ContainsKey(displayName))
                    {
                        int position = 0;                           
                        columnNames.TryGetValue(displayName, out position);
                        ////int position = columnNames.IndexOf(propertyInfo.Name);
                        ////To prevent an exception cast the value to the type of the property.
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(objT, Convert.ChangeType(wsRow[rowNum, position + 1].Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
                    }
                }                   
                retList.Add(objT);
            }

        }
        return retList;
    }
//IMPLEMENTATION DONE BY PLACING Code IT IN SEPARATE Helpers.CS file  and 
//Consuming it in this manner
List<CustomerExcelModel> records = 
Helpers.GetClassFromExcel<CustomerExcelModel>(filelocation, 1, 1);
```

Thanks a lot to the user who Submitted code and Andreas for suggestion
Here are the Following changes done, i am new to generics so forgive and correct me for any mistakes please find modified code below it might help someone

- Added  Display Annotation entity model to map with the Excel Column
  name so that Column Name with spaces can also be handled.
- had issue "T objT " as it was outside of  for loop and hence caused
  same value repeatedly inserted into List  fixed it by
  instantiating inside loop i.e using  "new T()"
- Fixed Column out of range error  by using "ws.Dimension.Columns" to get  Column count , instead of  ws.Cells.Count() as it caused out
  range column error
- for looping through row data added +1 to it  ,as RowNum=1 was reading header  name also so done minor change of "rowNum = fromRow + 1"

Answer (score 1):

Here I am sharing how you can read the excel. You can modify it to store each date in datatables.

```
public void readXLS(string FilePath)
{
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        //get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
        for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                //You can update code here to add each cell value to DataTable.
                Console.WriteLine(" Row:" + row + " column:" + col + " Value:" + worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reff: http://sforsuresh.in/read-data-excel-sheet-insert-database-table-c/

Answer (score 0):

Use below code if you want to read data of each worksheet from excel, as well if worksheet contain date format data for particular column.

```
public static DataSet ReadExcelFileToDataSet2(string filePath, bool isFirstRowHeader=true)

    {
        DataSet result = new DataSet();

        Excel.ExcelPackage xlsPackage = new Excel.ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath));  //using Excel = OfficeOpenXml;    <--EPPLUS
        Excel.ExcelWorkbook workBook = xlsPackage.Workbook;

        try
        {
            for (int count = 1; count <= workBook.Worksheets.Count; count++)
            {
                Excel.ExcelWorksheet wsworkSheet = workBook.Worksheets[count];

                if (wsworkSheet.Name.ToLower() == "sheetName")
                {
                    wsworkSheet.Column(4).Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM-dd-yyyy";  // set column value to read as Date Type or numberformat
                }

                DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                // wsworkSheet.Dimension - (It will return cell dimesion like A1:N7 , means returning the worksheet dimesions.)
                // wsworkSheet.Dimension.End.Address - (It will return right bottom cell like N7)
                // wsworkSheet.Dimension.End.Columns - (It will return count from A1 to N7  like here 14)
                foreach (var firstRowCell in wsworkSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, wsworkSheet.Dimension.End.Column])  //.Cells[Row start, Column Start, Row end, Column End]
                {
                   var colName = "";
                   colName = firstRowCell.Text;
                   tbl.Columns.Add(isFirstRowHeader ? colName : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));  //Geth the Column index (index starting with 1) from the left top.
                }
                var startRow = isFirstRowHeader ? 2 : 1;
                for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= wsworkSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                {
                    var wsRow = wsworkSheet.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, wsworkSheet.Dimension.End.Column]; //  wsworkSheet.Cells[Row start, Column Start, Row end, Column End]
                    DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                    {
                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                    }
                }

                tbl.TableName = wsworkSheet.Name;

                result.Tables.Add(tbl);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: When you're answering a 7 year old question, it would be much better if you could add a description as to what your answer does and how it adds to the 8 other answers that have already been posted.