# Get row number from EPPlus ExcelWorksheet based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

How would I go about getting the row number from an `ExcelWorksheet` object based upon matching criteria? For example, need something like this:

```
int row = from w in WorkSheet
          where w.(rowValue) == matchingValue &&
                w.(secondRowValue) == secondMatchingValue
          select w.rowNumber
```

Is this possible using EPPlus?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is load the sheet into a datatable using EPPlus like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13396787/1316683

Include the row number as the first column inside that loop, and then query the datatable:

```
DataRow[] matchingRow = myDataTable.Select(string.Format("rowValue = '{0}' AND secondRowValue = '{1}'", matchingValue, secondMatchingValue));
int row = matchingRow[0][0];
```