# Excel table to datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, import-from-excel

I am trying to add an entire Excel table into a datatable and declaring variables like this:

```
workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(fileString)
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Report")
```

It is able to read from the Excel file. I have checked using a message box:

```
MsgBox(worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value)
```

This works but I can't find a method to add the values from the Excel file into my datatable:

```
Dim table As New DataTable

table.Columns.Add("DATE")
table.Columns.Add("VALUE")
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some library to do it
For example NPOI ([example](http://svn.stellman-greene.com/PublicationHarvester/trunk/PubMed/NpoiHelper.cs)), or Epplus ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396604/excel-to-datatable-using-epplus-excel-locked-for-editing))
Or [use OleDb provider](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a4fae14-6764-4ccc-9781-845e3d035683/read-xls-file-to-import-to-datatable-but-no-need-to-install-any-com-component-dlls-etc-in-windows?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 1):

You can export a excel in  to datatable  using oledb

**NOTE:**

> since we are going to use oledb connection we have to Imports
>   System.Data.OleDb

Try the following code

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("date")
        dt.Columns.Add("value")
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        Time = System.DateTime.Now
        Try
            XLDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\name.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;""") 'give your file path in source
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw (ex)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        XLDbConnection.Open()
        Try
            XLDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$]", XLDbConnection) 'sheet1 is name of the excel sheet
            XLDbDataReader = XLDbCommand.ExecuteReader
        Catch ex As Exception

            Throw (ex)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        If XLDbDataReader.HasRows = True Then
            'Assign excel data to datacolumn of our datatable
            While XLDbDataReader.Read
                Try
                    dr("date") = XLDbDataReader.Item("date").ToString() 'column name as it is in excel file 
                    dr("value") = XLDbDataReader.Item("value").ToString()
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw (ex)
                End Try
            End While
        End If
```

hope this helps