# Importing Excel to DataTable getting data incorrectly using OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I am using OpenXML to import excel to a DataTable. My first row is merged to display only Title information and the second row is the header row. While populating DataTable from an excel file, I am getting incorrect data. The DataTable is populating correctly until any blank cell is present. When there are blank cells they are moving to the adjacent data presenting cell. Why is this happening? What is the problem in the code? Could you please help me to get the data in a proper way using OpenXML. Here are my Excel file and Data Table once data is imported.

**DataTable**
[image]

**Import_Data.xlsx**
[image]

My code sample is as below:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace OpenXMLDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            var data = p.ExtractExcel(@"C:\TempData\");
        }

        public System.Data.DataTable ExtractExcel(string fullPath)
        {
            var excelFileToImport = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "Data_Import.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            //Create a new DataTable.
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            //Open the Excel file in Read Mode using OpenXML
            using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelFileToImport[0], false))
            {
                WorksheetPart titlesWorksheetPart = GetWorksheetPart(doc.WorkbookPart, "Titles");

                Worksheet titlesWorksheet = titlesWorksheetPart.Worksheet;

                //Fetch all the rows present in the worksheet
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = titlesWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();

                //Loop through the Worksheet rows
                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                    if (row.RowIndex.Value == 1)
                    {

                    }
                    else if (row.RowIndex.Value == 2)
                    {
                        foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(GetValue(doc, cell));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Add rows to DataTable.
                        dt.Rows.Add();
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                        {
                            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = GetValue(doc, cell);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
        private string GetValue(SpreadsheetDocument doc, Cell cell)
        {
            string value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
            if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
        {
            string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => sheetName.Equals(s.Name)).Id;
            return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# OPEN XML: empty cells are getting skipped while getting data from EXCEL to DATATABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100011/c-sharp-open-xml-empty-cells-are-getting-skipped-while-getting-data-from-excel)

Comment: Empty cells are not listed - so you would need to check the CellReference to see which column to store the cell data in. The link above shows how do do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the part of the code with the help of the link provided by PaulF. Thanks!!!

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace OpenXMLDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            System.Data.DataTable data = p.ExtractExcel(@"C:\TempData\");
        }

        public System.Data.DataTable ExtractExcel(string fullPath)
        {
            var excelFileToImport = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "Data_Import.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            //Create a new DataTable.
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            //Open the Excel file in Read Mode using OpenXML
            using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelFileToImport[0], false))
            {
                WorksheetPart titlesWorksheetPart = GetWorksheetPart(doc.WorkbookPart, "Titles");

                Worksheet titlesWorksheet = titlesWorksheetPart.Worksheet;

                //Fetch all the rows present in the worksheet
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = titlesWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();

                foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(1))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(doc, cell)); // this will include 2nd row a header row
                }

                //Loop through the Worksheet rows
                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex.Value > 2) //this will exclude first two rows
                    {
                        System.Data.DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();
                        int columnIndex = 0;
                        foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                        {
                            // Gets the column index of the cell with data
                            int cellColumnIndex = (int)GetColumnIndexFromName(GetColumnName(cell.CellReference));
                            cellColumnIndex--; //zero based index
                            if (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex)
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    tempRow[columnIndex] = ""; //Insert blank data here;
                                    columnIndex++;
                                }
                                while (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex);
                            }
                            tempRow[columnIndex] = GetCellValue(doc, cell);

                            columnIndex++;
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
        public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
        {
            SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
            if (cell.CellValue == null)
            {
                return "";
            }
            string value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;
            if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Given a cell name, parses the specified cell to get the column name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cellReference">Address of the cell (ie. B2)</param>
        /// <returns>Column Name (ie. B)</returns>
        public static string GetColumnName(string cellReference)
        {
            // Create a regular expression to match the column name portion of the cell name.
            Regex regex = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+");
            Match match = regex.Match(cellReference);
            return match.Value;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Given just the column name (no row index), it will return the zero based column index.
        /// Note: This method will only handle columns with a length of up to two (ie. A to Z and AA to ZZ). 
        /// A length of three can be implemented when needed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Column Name (ie. A or AB)</param>
        /// <returns>Zero based index if the conversion was successful; otherwise null</returns>
        public static int? GetColumnIndexFromName(string columnName)
        {
            //return columnIndex;
            string name = columnName;
            int number = 0;
            int pow = 1;
            for (int i = name.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                number += (name[i] - 'A' + 1) * pow;
                pow *= 26;
            }
            return number;
        }
        public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
        {
            string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => sheetName.Equals(s.Name)).Id;
            return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
        }
    }
}
```