# Read Excel file without headers ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to follow [this code](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/277/reading-excel-files-without-saving-to-disk-in-asp-net) to read Excel files. Unfortunately, I cannot make it work, because I need to read Excel files without headers. How can I read an Excel files without headers?

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this ExcelPackage package)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();


        foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
        }

        for (var rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
        {
            var row = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];
            var newRow = table.NewRow();
            foreach (var cell in row)
            {
                    newRow[cell.Start.Column-1] = cell.Text;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(newRow);  
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: maybe try something like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396604/excel-to-datatable-using-epplus-excel-locked-for-editing with `bool hasHeader = false;`

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the `for` statement that it loops starting from the second row (skipping the header), what you need is to loop from the first row (as there is no header row) like this:

```
var rowNumber = 1
```

If your data is empty at the first row, then please add how many columns you are expecting to be there in the file:

```
// Notice I replaced workSheet.Dimension.End.Column with 6, because I am expecting 6 columns.
foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 6])
{
    table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
}
```

Comment: Changed it to 1 but it gives me an error says the cannot find column 0.

Comment: Line 30:                         newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;

Comment: Basically the excel file's structure is the first row is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a work around with the problem. I automatically added columns. Changing to foreach to a for loop.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; x++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(x.ToString());
        }
```