# Excel export in normal text format

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I currently am writing a system that includes reading in excel files. I want to read in this excel file and potentially spew it out into a csv. However, the issue im running into is that it is keeping the format that excel uses. For example i have a long number that in excel displays as 3.9151+E15, and it reads it in like this. When i highlight the cell in excel it shows the real number '3915100000026840'. This is the number i want to receive. It also adds a timestamp to dates which i do not want. It adds 00:00 00:00:000 or something similar to 17/05/2018, which is all i want. So basically, i want to retrieve the real text values from this excel spreadsheet.

The code i have at the minute is

```
    public static DataTable READExcel(string path)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
        objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = objWB.Worksheets[1];

        int rows = objSHT.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        int cols = objSHT.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int noofrow = 1;

        for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
        {
            string colname = objSHT.Cells[1, c].Value.ToString();
            dt.Columns.Add(colname);
            noofrow = 2;
        }

        for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
            {
                dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Value.ToString();
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        objWB.Close();
        objXL.Quit();
        return dt;
    }
```

(Also another question which is slightly related but slightly not related, i had a csv to start which had the value '0003915100000026845'. When i turned this csv into a excel file it changed it to the value i reference above. Will excel have remembered these leading zeros anywhere or not?)

Comment: Hi, this unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't read the code.I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: Have you looked into the EpPlus library? You should have all the functionality you want right out the box and not have to deal with (terrible) interop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13396604/1693085

Comment: This seems to have worked John, many thanks. I'm thinking for the question i had at the bottom that excel just gets rid of these leading 0s so i dont think there's anything i can do about those.